# How to intersect two or more matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let say I have some number of matrices with non-negative entries, N matrices for example of equal sizes MxM. For example, I have 3 matrices as follow:

```
A1=[2, 2, 0;
    2, 2, 0;
    0, 2, 0];


A2=[4, 0, 4;
    4, 3, 0;
    0, 0, 1];


A3=[2, 0, 0;
    1, 0, 3;
    3, 4, 3];
```

I want to find the intersection of A1, A2, and A3 in matlab. That means I want to get the follow matrix:

```
 B=[-1,  2,  4;
    -1, -1,  3;
     3, -1, -1];
```

If the intersection of the (i, j) element of the N matrices, i.e., the elements A1(i, j), A2(i, j), A3(i, j), is at most one nonzero number then B(i,j) equals that number. Else if the intersection is at least two numbers I output -1 as I showed in the previous example.

How can I do this in matlab without loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, concatenate to a single 3D-Matrix:

```
A=cat(3,A1,A2,A3)
```

Then count the non-zero elements, which gives the location of the `-1`-Elements:

```
L=(sum(A~=0,3)>1)
```

Finally, There where L=1 we want a -1, otherwise we want the single element at that location, which is the sum because the others are zero:

```
L*-1+(1-L).*sum(A,3)
```

Comment: If the non zero elements are the same then I will get a -1. If the intersection of the element (i, j) of the matrices is the same number then output that number.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Sorry. If for example A2(1, 1)=2 instead of 4. Then using your code I will get -1 in B(1, 1). I want to have 2 instead of -1. I asked a new question please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670915/intersection-of-matrices-in-matlab.

Comment: I tried to do it this way: L=(sum(A~=0, 3)>1&A1==A2&A1==A3&A2=A3)

Comment: Your new question explains it well, I answered it.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it something like so:

First, count up the non-zero elements at each location across all matrices:

```
foo = (A1 ~= 0) + (A2 ~= 0) + (A3 ~= 0);
```

Next, find those which have more than one non-zero element, and set them to -1 in the result:

```
B = zeros(3,3);
B(foo > 1) = -1;
```

Finally, find the non-zero elements (since in the elements we care about there is only one non-zero element, this is the same as the sum across matrices)

```
sumA = A1 + A2 + A3;
```

And add them into the result matrix

```
B(foo == 1) = sumA(foo == 1);
```