# Intersection of matrices in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

It is almost the same question as this one [Matrices intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584148/how-to-intersect-two-or-more-matrices)!

The difference is this: If the intersection of the element (i, j) of all matrices is the same number then do not output -1 but output this number. An example is the following:

```
A1 = [2, 2, 0;
      2, 2, 0;
      0, 2, 0];


A2 = [2, 0, 4;
      4, 3, 0;
      0, 0, 1];


A3 = [2, 0, 0;
      1, 0, 3;
      3, 4, 3];
```

I want to get the follow matrix:

```
 B = [2,  2,  4;
     -1, -1,  3;
      3, -1, -1];
```

Comment: I would recommend not posting the question a second time, especially within a few days of each other. Simply modify your other question to make it more clear what you are asking.

Comment: @MZimmerman6: I don't think so. Modifying already answered questions can be very confusing to anyone who reads it later.

Comment: What if only the two corresponding elements in A1 and A2 are same, but  in A3 is different. Are we taking `max` of those three elements? It looks like so to me, from your `B`.

Comment: @Daniel I think it is highly case dependent, but I feel like a change to the previous question would not be highly confusion as long as it is denoted that things were changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Version 1**

```
out1 = -1.*(A1~=A2).*(A1~=A3).*(A2~=A3)
max_mat = max(cat(3,A1,A2,A3),[],3)
out1(~out1) = max_mat(~out1)
```

**Output**

```
out1 =

     2     2     4
    -1    -1     3
     3    -1    -1
```

**Version 2: Maybe a faster version**

**Assumption -** If out of the three elements in the corresponding positions across A1, A2 and A3, only two are same, then take the max of those three elements for the final matrix, B.

**Code**

```
%%// Concatenate all three A matrices
A=cat(3,A1,A2,A3,A1);

%%// Logical matrix with ones where all three elements are different from each other
out1 = -1.*all(diff(A,[],3)~=0,3)

%%// Get the max values, to be stored where -1 all three corresponding elements 
%%// are not different from each other
max_mat = max(A,[],3)

%%// Get the final output
out1(~out1) = max_mat(~out1)
```

This produces the same output as the previous version.

**Version 3**

**Assumption -** If out of the three elements in the corresponding positions across A1, A2 and A3, only two are same, then take the element that is different from the other two for the final matrix, B.

**Code**

```
A=cat(3,A1,A2,A3,A1);
AA = A(:,:,1:3);
t1 = bsxfun(@ne,AA,mode(AA,3));
out1 = max(AA.*t1,[],3) + all(~t1,3).*A1;
out1(all(diff(A,[],3)~=0,3))=-1;
```

This produces the same output as the previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

```
A1 = [2, 2, 0;
      2, 2, 0;
      0, 2, 0];


A2 = [2, 0, 4;
      4, 3, 0;
      0, 0, 1];


A3 = [2, 0, 0;
      1, 0, 3;
      3, 4, 3];
A=cat(3,A1,A2,A3);

%identify all fields with identical values on the 3rd dimension
[X,Y]=find(sum(abs(diff(A,1,3)),3)==0);
%delete all but the first repetition, then use the previous code
A(X,Y,2:end)=0;

L=(sum(A~=0,3)>1);

L*-1+(1-L).*sum(A,3)
```

/update: Had to fix the code, now it should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this

```
A = A1+A2+A3;
B = (A1==A2)&(A1==A3);
C = (A1==0)+(A2==0)+(A3==0);

D = ones(3)*-1;
D(B==1) = A1(B==1);
D(C==2) = A(C==2);
```

- `B` records the position of the elements whose number is same for all the matrices.
- `C` records the position of the elements where two of the matrices have 0.

Then we can modify the elements of `D`, whose values are set -1 initially, using the information in matrices `B` and `C`.